# Set WPF Font size based on screen size

Tags: .net, wpf, styles

I'd like to have a default font size that is based on the users screen resolution.
ie if screen work area width is less than 1024 use font size 10 else use font size 14.
Am currently using the "SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width" to determine the width

I can set a global font size and have a converter to return a font size, but am really struggling to work out how to make it fire. ie. when the window size changes, make it check what the font size should be

```
<Window.Resources>

    <local:SetFontSize x:Key="myConverter" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="baseStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"  />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />           

</Window.Resources>
```

I have found the below event, but just can't seem to link the two together (although I might be going about this wrong way)

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SizeChanged">          
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want this anyway?
Wpf uses abstract coordinates, and convert them to pixels using the current Monitor DPI and resolution. So, your application should automatically scale to look similar on every screen.
I would suggest, using stretchy layout, with scrollbars, etc. To enabled your app being used on smaller screens.

Comment: Thanks guys, I do appreciate what both of you are saying and will reconsider my approach. I still find that regardless of the DPI setting, there is a massive difference in text size between say an 800 x 600  and say 1920 x 1200, eg. I can make a text box strech but can't make the corresponding label 'font strech' which can make things look odd.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that WPF apps are 'DPI-aware' and font sizes are not in pixels - so if the user uses a different DPI setting to increase font size, it will be reflected in your WPF app automatically.  Hopefully it's a possibility for users to use the DPI setting as they should?

(If other apps use font size 10 and it's too small, rather than rewrite that app they'd probably adjust their DPI - if no other apps use font size 10, it's probably too small for all users)

I realise this is a non-answer, but it's a shame to sacrifice design and have to hack stuff in for a people who won't adjust their DPI setting?  Am I being too negative? :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the control in a grid and viewbox. It will fit the container in every resolution.

```
 <Grid Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
     <Viewbox>
     <TextBox/>
     </Viewbox>
   </Grid>
```